# Symantec Backup Exec can't see network shares

Tags: backup, nfs, backupexec, symantec

I have a CentOS 6 host with a NFS export where I have stored some virtual machine backups.
Now I want those backups to tape for archival. I have mounted the share to a drive letter under Windows 2003 R2 and can see the contents of the share.

I mounted the share as follows :

```
mount nfsserver:/nfs w:
```

I am using the same user that mounted the share to run Symantec Backup Exec. I even tried to share the folder through CIFS and after connecting the folder to a network drive SBE can't see the drive either.

The problem is I don't see this drive letter from Symantec Backup exec (12). Browsing the *NFS network* (that's how Symantec names it) doesn't work either. Is this a nasty feature or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

The Backup Exec service (generally) does not run as the same user you'd use to administer the system. Instead, it lets you create (or creates for you) some special service accounts just for itself. Let's say your logged-in user is drcelus@domain.local. The "drive letter" you connected to the NFS share only exists in the context of drcelus@domain.local user, not any other. You'll need to find some other way to map that NFS share.

Trivial web searching on the matter yields very little good news on using Backup Exec and NFS in this way. If at all possible, turn that NFS export into a CIFS share and you're in business.

Comment: I am running Backup Exec under the same user that mounted the drive letter, I am starting to fear this have something to do with the user mapping service that uses the NFS client under windows.